# systemd: lightdm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE / How to log whats happening in a early stage of the booting process

Tags: shell-script, systemd, boot, logs, runlevel

I've upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 on my ARM (32 bit armhf) Chromebook. While Ubuntu 18.04 works perfectly,Ubuntu 20.04 has some kind of problem. I think that during the upgrade something broken.

At the beginning I've added this lines in rc.local :

```
journalctl --boot --no-pager > /home/linux/log 
exit 0
```

and I've got this log file : https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/QZMygg8cjP/

unfortunately,later,the same technique stopped working. It didn't produce that log file anymore. I tried to execute different commands and binary files putting them before and after "exit 0" on the file /etc/rc.local,but nothing has been created anymore. For example :

```
echo > /home/linux/ciao1
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
echo > /home/linux/ciao2
journalctl --boot --no-pager > /home/linux/log0
/bin/journalctl --boot --no-pager > /home/linux/log1
/bin/./journalctl --boot --no-pager > /home/linux/log2
/bin/./journalctl --boot --no-pager > /log3
journalctl --boot --no-pager > /log4
exit 0
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
echo > /home/linux/ciao3
```

What do you suggest me to do to ? I imagine that I should understand why it doesnt create a log file anymore and / or I should choose another technique to produce the log file from a different run level ? Anyway,I want to understand how to fix it.